# Memory Leaks In audio?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I can Create a simple application on android,and use sound effects form 5 audios file, but i cannot release memory for object.

```
mBackground = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.intro);
        mRiver  = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.river);
        mClapping = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ap);
        mTap = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.tap);
        mError = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.error);
        mWonder = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ap2);
        if(GameDashBoard.soundInGame) {mBackground.start(); mBackground.setLooping(true);
```

And can Release memory but this code not working.

```
mRiver.release();
mClapping.release();
mTap.release();
mWonder.release();
```

**Problem is print on log cat** ---- Audio cache heap overflow.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: *"Please solve my problem for a great answer.

Thanks.."*  Please ask a question (no, the title is not a question) and leave such noise out of posts.

Comment: sorry, my question is-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085025/memory-leaks-in-audio

Answer (score 0):

soundpool will keep all the sounds in memory. A single instance of media player would probably be all you need [see here](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/android-soundpool-vs-mediaplayer-focus-on-soundboards-and-memory-problems/). You should do this and your memory issues should go away without having to go to any extreme measures.